# Redirect to Action with an ID that is retrieved from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently have an application that uses AJAX with FullCalendar.

I would like to be able for the User to click an item on this calendar, a dialog appear with a button saying "View Details". This will then bring the user to that specific Event Page.

I have the dialog working but I am getting so confused on how to get the ID out of the AJAX call and put it into a Javascript function to redirect to that action.

I think I know how to get it to go to that action but I don't know how I'm going to get the ID out of the AJAX call.

Here's my FullCalendar,which works:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Appointments/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        details: v.DetailsOfAppointment,
                        date: moment(v.DateOfAppointment),
                        room: v.RoomType,
                        confirmed: v.Confirmed,
                        colour: v.ThemeColour,
                        church: v.Church.Name,
                        parishAdminName: v.Admins.AdministratorName,
                        parishAdminUser: v.Admins.AdminUsername,
                        parishAdminId: v.Admins.AdministratorId,
                        fee: v.Fee,
                        id: v.AppointmentId

                    });

                })
                 GenerateCalender(events);   
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("failed");
                console.log(error);
            }
        })

        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 500,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: events.ThemeColour,
                events: events,
                aspectRatio: 2.2,
                minTime: "09:00:00",
                maxTime: "17:00:00",
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    if (event.fee == null) {
                        if (event.confirmed == false) {
                            element.css('background-color', '#FF0000');
                            element.css('border-color', '#FF0000');
                        }
                        else {
                            element.css('background-color', '#008000');
                            element.css('border-color', '#008000');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.css('background-color', '#0000FF');
                        element.css('border-color', '#0000FF');

                    }
                },
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#myModal #details').text(calEvent.details);
                    var $details = $('<div/>');

                    if (calEvent.fee != null) {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Ceremony : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    else {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Appointment : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Details : </b>' + calEvent.details));
                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Church Name : </b>' + calEvent.church));
                    if (calEvent.fee == null) {
                        if (calEvent.room != null) {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room : </b>' + calEvent.room));
                        }
                        else {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room Not Confirmed'));
                        }
                    }
                    $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Parish Admin : </b>' + calEvent.parishAdminName));
                    if (calEvent.confirmed == true)
                    {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Confirmed </b>'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Not Confirmed </b>'));
                    }
                    $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($details);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                },

                eventDrop: function (event) {
                    var data = {
                        AppointmentID: event.id,
                    };
                }

            })
        }

    })

    $('#viewDetails').click(function (id) {
        window.location.href = '/Appointments/Details/' + id;
    }
</script>
```

I know its something so simple but I honestly can't think.

**EDIT** Here's my button if it helps

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
                <button id="viewDetails" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    View Details
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the redirect a javascript action, could you just make the #viewDetails link's HREF point to the page you want?  If it's currently a button you could make it a link styled to look like a button.

For example, at the end of the script that builds and shows the modal you could try something like this:

```
$('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($details);

$('#viewDetails').attr("href", '/Appointments/Details/' + calEvent.id);

$('#myModal').modal();
```

And change your button to a link, such as:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p id="pDetails"></p>
    <a href="" id="viewDetails" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right:5px;">
        View Details
    </a>
</div>
```